# Install A Specific Version of Boost With Homebrew on Mac

Tags: c++, boost, homebrew

I am trying to install an older version of Boost on my Mac using Homebrew.

I am using:

```
brew install boost@1.53
```

And receiving error:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "boost@1.53"
```

I have performed:

```
brew search boost
```

And I can see that I have all versions back to 1.55 installed.

Is there a way round this, how can I install 1.53?

Answer (score 0):

Git clone the boost code, checkout the version that you want and compile.

Comment: Hi Sunil. Is there no way of doing this from the command line?

Comment: @Sunil is right. You can only install by manual installation. Homebew does not support versions before 1.55.